# what will be the best way to parse string inside 2 characters

Tags: c#

i have this string:

**"Network adapter 'Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller' on local host"**

what will be the best way to return only the string between "'" ? (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller)

Comment: if you know that there are excactly two '' you can loop through the characters. You can use a Regex or you can use IndexOf and LastIndexOf with Substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Substring()` method to chop it up.

```
tempStr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("'")+1);
yourStr = tempStr.SubString(0, tempStr.IndexOf("'"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with regular expressions, you could use a pattern like:

```
/'[^']*'/
```

to capture everything between the single quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

```
var s = "hello 'world' hehe";
var m = Regex.Match(s, "'([^']*)'");
string res = null;
if (m.Success) {
    res = m.Groups[1].ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

The key to the solution is this regular expression:

```
'([^']*)'
```

It starts the match when it finds a single quote, and continues until it finds the closing quote, capturing everything in between. The captured group is then retrieved through the `Regex` API. Note that the capturing groups that you define start at index `1`; index zero is reserved to mean "the entire match".

Take a look at the [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/46IfFZ).